# Unable to change the priority of a 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout' constraint programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

It seems that if I wanted to lower my 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' through the storyboard, it would be quite easy. Although I am having trouble finding the current constraint because I've been using auto-layout and programmed my views programmatically.  I seek to do this because the TableView I'm using is having some type of default height overwritten when it has been reloaded and although my application is running as intended, the debugger is being polluted with...

```
'    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c048d7a0 V:|-(0)-[NetworkPostDemo.NewsFeedCellView:0x10ff569e0]   (active, names: '|':NetworkPostDemo.NewsFeedTableViewCell:0x10414ca00'news' )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c048d840 NetworkPostDemo.NewsFeedCellView:0x10ff569e0.bottom == NetworkPostDemo.NewsFeedTableViewCell:0x10414ca00'news'.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c048e5b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' NetworkPostDemo.NewsFeedTableViewCell:0x10414ca00'news'.height == 44   (active)>"'
```

I believe the problem truly lies here:

```
workPostDemo.NewsFeedTableViewCell:0x10414ca00'news'.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c048e5b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' NetworkPostDemo.NewsFeedTableViewCell:0x10414ca00'news'.height == 44   (active)>"
```

Where can I lower this constraint property programmatically?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The heights of the table view's cells aren't automatically adjusting?

Comment: You can set the cell height for table by setting `tableView.rowHeight` or `tableView.estimatedRowHeight`. Or if you just need to override individual cells you can use delegate `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @slickdaddy The heights are readjusting, but the debugger is being polluted with warnings about having to break constraints.

Comment: @Tom, I have added an estimated height to no avail.

Comment: It appears you have a constraint conflict in one of the cells. Auto layout is sometimes smart enough to render everything correctly even though there are constraint conflicts. How many cells in the table?

Comment: Is the 'news' object mentioned in the warning perhaps bigger than 44?

Comment: @slickdaddy 25 cells, about

Comment: @Tom, i have set no contraint to 44, it seems that is the default for a tableview cell and I am seeking to override it.

Comment: @TravisBaksh load the table cell by cell until you find the one that is giving you a warning